# WinJS Two way Binding returning undefined

Tags: data-binding, winjs

I am new to window8 development, I am basically trying to implement this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651576.aspx
I am using the view model as in figure8 in the link example, but I am unable to display the data, it shows the undefine, but if I only give one element of array I am able to bind it.

My UI is

```
<body>
   <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
      <!-- display each person -->
      <div id="nameLabel">Name</div>
      <input id="name" readonly="true" type="text" data-win-bind="value: name" />
      <div id="ageLabel">Age</div>
      <input id="age" readonly="true" type="text" data-win-bind="value: age" />
      <div id="colorLabel">Favorite Color</div>
      <div id="color" data-win-bind="style.backgroundColor:favoriteColor"></div>
      <div id="buttons">
        <button id="previousButton"></button>
        <button id="birthdayButton"></button>
        <button id="nextButton"></button>
      </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

and the JavaScript contains

```
 var people = [
      // Notify binding listeners when these objects change
      WinJS.Binding.as({ name: "John", age: 18, favoriteColor: "red" }),
      WinJS.Binding.as({ name: "Tom", age: 16, favoriteColor: "green" }),
      WinJS.Binding.as({ name: "Chris", age: 42, favoriteColor: "blue" }),
            ];
            // Bind the current person to the HTML elements in the section
            var section = document.querySelector("section[role=main]");
            var current = 0;
            var viewModel = WinJS.Binding.as({ person: people[current+1] });
            WinJS.Binding.processAll(section, viewModel);
            nextButton.onclick = function () {
                current = (people.length + current + 1) % people.length;
                viewModel.person = people[current];
            };
```

This is the result:

[image: binding result]

Please help me to bind the UI with data model. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens because you've double wrapped a `person` with a `WinJS.Binding`. When you did that, you need to change the property path to:

```
data-win-bind="value: person.name"
```

When you created the `viewModel` property, it created a new property containing the actual `person` instance:

```
var viewModel = WinJS.Binding.as({ person: people[current+1] });
```

Also, note that there isn't two-way binding in WinJs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am able to see the first item on list, but whenever I click on next button it does not show the second item from list. Would you help me with this

Comment: You start binding on the second `people` item, rather than the first in your code: `person: people[current+1]`. I'd expect it to be `person: people[current]`. It's a zero based array.